# Second Largest Value with criteria in excel

Tags: excel, max

I'm trying to find the second largest value of a given criteria in excel. So the formula I was trying to use was

`=LARGE(IF($B$1:$B$216=1,$F$1:$F$216,""),2)`.

The problem is that it is returning the second largest overall value, but I want the second largest value where column B is 1. Better Answers would be helpful.

Comment: It is an array formula you have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter at the same time instead of just enter

Answer (score 2):

You are using an **array (CSE) formula** and you did not enter it the key combination for array formuas. Edit the cell again and click `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Or if you want a normal (non CSE) formula, use this:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$F$1:$F$216/($B$1:$B$216=1),2)
```

Comment: Psssssst. AGGREGATE()

Comment: Could you please explain how the division symbol works here ?  I got it to work for me but just don't understand how.  Thank you !