# Return the largest value (and corresponding label) in a column based on given criteria

Tags: excel

So I have an Excel sheet with three columns: **Value ($M)**, **Contract Name**, and **Year** [of Contract Award].

Image of Data: [image: Contract Value, Name, Year Data]

I am trying to return the **Contract Name** of the contracts with the 3 largest values. I found the solution to that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528624/extracting-the-top-5-maximum-values-in-excel).

`=INDEX($B$2:$B$21,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$21=LARGE($A$2:$A$21,E2))*(COUNTIF(E2,$B$2:$B$21)=0),),))`

However, I have an added caveat: I only want to pull contracts from 2017. I found the solution for pulling the values from 2017 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607691/second-largest-value-with-criteria-in-excel) using a CSE formula and adjusted the formula accordingly:

`{=INDEX($B$2:$B$21,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$21=LARGE(IF($C$2:$C$21=2017,$A$2:$A$21),E2))*(COUNTIF(E2,$B$2:$B$21)=0),),))}`

When I incorporate that into the formula it works fine on returning only the top 3 values from 2017, however because one of the top 3 values from 2017 is a duplicate of a 2015 value, it is picking up the contract name from 2015.

Image of Results: [image: Results]

As shown on the above image, it is pulling *"Contract 1"* from 2015 for $100M as opposed to *"Contract 8"* from 2017 for $100M. Any idea how to adjust my formula to only pick up the contract names from 2017? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula in cell `F2`. There is no need for helper column.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$21,MATCH(LARGE(IF($C$2:$C$21=2017,$A$2:$A$21,0), ROW()-1), IF($C$2:$C$21=2017,$A$2:$A$21,0), 0),1)
```

Since this is an array formula, please confirm it with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, it's worked wonderfully. However, Is there any adjustment that could be made to this to ensure that it doesn't pull duplicate names? For example, say that I have two contracts (Column B) in 2017 with the same value (Column A). I'm currently getting a duplicate Contract Name in my results for two different contracts of the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a helper column to get your result.

I inserted a helper column into **Column A** that includes the formula

`=IF($D2=2017,COUNTIF($B$2:$B$21,">="&$B2),"")`

where `$B$2:$B$21` is the full column of data in **Value ($M)**, `$B2` is the first cell under **Value ($M)**, and **2017** is the year for which you're pulling data, so adjust each as needed. Drag this formula down the entire length of your helper column.

*Side note: If the year you are trying to pull for can change, consider adding a dedicated cell that is meant for holding the requested year. This cell will then replace **2017** in my suggested formula.*

Then in `$G$1` enter the following formula:

`=INDEX($B$2:$C$21,MATCH(SMALL($A$2:$A$21,$F2),$A$2:$A$21,0),2)`

where, again, `$B$2:$B$21` is the full column of data in **Value ($M)**, `$F2` is the value of 1 under **Rank**, and `$A$2:$A$21` is the full column of data in the helper column. Drag this formula down for the other two rows in **Rank**.

You can then use the same formula in **Column H**, but only change the `2` at the very end of the formula to `1`, like so:

`=INDEX($B$2:$C$21,MATCH(SMALL($A$2:$A$21,$F2),$A$2:$A$21,0),1)`.

If you end up having multiple contracts in the same year with the exact same **Value ($M)**, it's going to place them in a rank order according to which shows up in the list first.

[image: Using a helper column to find rank values]