# EXCEL Get top 3 largest numbers in repetitive array

Tags: excel, numbers, match

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt6eo.png)I have an array of people with scores in other column. I need to find top 3 people with highest score and print their names.

Example:

```
Maria  1
Thomas 4
John   3
Jack   2
Ray    2
Laura  4
Kate   3
```

Result should be:

```
Thomas
Laura 
John
```

What I get:

```
Thomas
Thomas
John
```

What I get:

```
Thomas
John
num
```

I have tried using LARGE, MATCH, MIN, MAX but nothings works.

My first failure code:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8;  MATCH(LARGE(($B$2:$B$8);{1;2;3}); $B$2:$B$8;0))
```

My second failure code:

```
{=INDEX($A$2:$A$14;SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$14=MAX($B$2:$B$14);ROW($B$2:$B$14)-1);ROW(B4)-1))}
```

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499572/4961700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the second row of the column you want:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$1:$B$7)/((COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$1:$A$7)=0)*($B$1:$B$7=LARGE(B:B,ROW(1:1)))),1))
```

And drag down three rows:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! Could you please explain it, or post other example with asc order?

Comment: The AGGREGATE returns the row number where both `(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$1:$A$7)=0)` and `($B$1:$B$7=LARGE(B:B,ROW(1:1)))`  are true.  The first makes sure it is unique and the second that it equals the appropriate value.

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Make sure you are using `;` instead of the `,` that I use.

Comment: I have new work to do. There is my formula =INDEX($A$4:$A$16;AGGREGATE(15;7;ROW($H$4:$H$16)/((COUNTIF($I$22:I25;$A$4:$A$16)=0)*($H$4:$H$16=LARGE($H$4:$H$16;3)));1))

I have A4:A16 and H4:H16 And I have to write the answer to the I23:I25

Comment: `=INDEX($A$4:$A$16` should be `=INDEX($A:$A`

Comment: It is really hard to find the error without the data to back up. I would suggest starting back with the dataset as I have it, make sure it works, then adjust that data set to match yours.

Comment: Could you give me skype or somethong like that, that I could send you a picture of my work. I'm really lost because it didin't work for me...

Comment: No, sorry but I like my privacy.

Comment: I edited my post and added a photo there. If you can, please, look at this, and correct my mistakes.

Comment: No where in my answer did I tell you to array enter.  Enter the formula in the first cell, hit enter then copy down.  This should be the first formula: `=INDEX($A$4:$A$16;AGGREGATE(15;7;ROW($H$4:$H$16)/((COUNTIF($I$22:I22;$A$4:$A$16)=0)*($H$4:$H$16=LARGE($H$4:$H$16;ROW(1:1))));1)`  Put that in I23, hit Enter then copy down.  Do not Array enter.

Comment: sorry the formula should be: `=INDEX($A:$A;AGGREGATE(15;7;ROW($H$4:$H$16)/((COUNTIF($I$22:I22;$A$4:$A$16)=0)*($H$4:$H$16=LARGE($H$4:$H$16;ROW(1:1))));1)`